# WITH & UNNEST in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I find it helpful to use `WITH` blocks to break up logic in a query. Am I correct in thinking I can't do this on a nested field within an `ARRAY` expression? I can separate into nested queries - which is sufficient but not ideal.

For example, this works:

```
SELECT
  repository.url,
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    action
  FROM (
    SELECT
      action
    FROM
      UNNEST(payload.pages))) action
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
```

...but this doesn't:

```
SELECT
  repository.url,
  ARRAY(
  WITH
    p AS (
    SELECT
      action
    FROM
      UNNEST(payload.pages))
  SELECT
    action
  FROM
    p) action
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
```

...`Error: Unrecognized name: payload at [9:14]`. Potentially because the table hasn't yet been defined for that `WITH` block?

Is there another way to do this?

EDIT: This is toy query to illustrate the issue, not representative of the actual queries we're running

Answer (score 4):

The only option I see is just to simplify/optimize your query to below - so there will be no need for WITH inside ARRAY

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  repository.url,
  ARRAY(SELECT action FROM UNNEST(payload.pages)) action
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. This is a toy query for display purposes only; the actual queries are more complex

Comment: the point of my answer was - you cannot use WITH inside ARRAY or any other expression. And I just tried to show you direction in case if you hav not realized that your query was overengineered a little

Comment: I appreciate your effort!